# second order ODE help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, quadratics

I am trying to solve this ODE:

$$W''(t)+2W'(t)-(\lambda-1)W(t)=0.$$

where $\lambda=-(n\pi)^2$

I used the quadratic formula to give me $r=-1+n\pi i$ and $ r=-1-n\pi i$
hence $W=e^{-t}(C_1\cos(n\pi t)+ C_2\sin(n\pi t))$.

Is this correct?

Comment: What is the characteristic equation ?

Comment: You can check to see if your answer is correct by looking to see if it satisfies the differential equation.

Comment: Why the downvotes and close votes? The poster asked a reasonable question and showed his work.

Comment: @rogerl. I did not downvote this question but I am still waiting for the answer to my question.

Comment: made amistake editing

Comment: sorry for the last response the characteristic equation is $r^2+2r-(\lambda -1) $

Answer (score 1):

The caharacteristic equation is $r^2+2r-(\lambda-1)=0$ and the roots are $r=-1+\sqrt{-\lambda}$ and $r=-1-\sqrt{-\lambda}$.

If  $\lambda< 0$ then there are real roots.

If $\lambda>0$, there are complex roots:
$r=-1-i\sqrt{\lambda}$ and $r=-1-i\sqrt{\lambda}$.

In this case the corresponding solution is $$W=\displaystyle e^{-t}\big( (c_1\sin(\sqrt{\lambda} t)+c_2\cos(\sqrt{\lambda} t)\big).$$

Comment: sorry for the late response would the answer be the same if $\lambda =-(n\pi)^2$

Comment: yes just put it into the equation.

Comment: ok I attempted the question again but i got $r=-1+sqrt(\lambda) \; r=-1-sqrt(\lambda)$

Comment: you mean when you put $\lambda=-(n\pi)^2$.

Comment: no before i put the lambda i think there must of been a mistake in your solution when finding the r's

Comment: yes you are right I edited

Comment: you're welcome  regards